# DataTemplate for Listbox containing lists as items doesn't get displayed

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, stackpanel, itemtemplate

I have the following data template for a list box items:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="substanceListShower">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then I apply the item template like this:

```
 ReactantInterfacesListBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("substanceListShower");
```

But in the list for the items i get a ToString() return:

`System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPanelTemplate`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an `ItemsPanelTemplate` to your `ListBox`, your definition lacks the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` tags to set the property instead.