# Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. But i'm not mixing

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listbox

I have this problem that I've been a while looking for a solution, I read all other related post but none resembles my scenario.
My code is a program that shows (and only that) the amount of product that is in process in a food factory

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductTemplate">
        <Grid d:DesignWidth="551.412" d:DesignHeight="54.172">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="139"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="53"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="ReadyAvailable"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="26.667" Margin="0,0,0,0.172" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Ready}"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="NextAvailable" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0.172" ItemsSource="{Binding NextAvailable}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource NextAvailableTemplate}">
                <ListBox.DataContext>
                    <local:Cooks/>
                </ListBox.DataContext>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Label x:Name="ProductName" Content="{Binding CookingProduct.ShortName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0.172" FontSize="21.333" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NextAvailableTemplate">
        <Grid d:DesignWidth="131.834" d:DesignHeight="54.172" Height="43">
            <Label x:Name="CounterString" Content="{Binding TimerString}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="21.333">
                <Label.DataContext>
                    <local:Cooks/>
                </Label.DataContext>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name="lbCooks" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ProductTemplate}" SelectionChanged="lbCook_SelectionChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <local:ProcessedProduct/>
    </ListBox.DataContext>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see is a listbox that lists product, the name, the amount that is already produced and available, and within the next listbox products that are next to be finished and available.

I Use Entity Framwork 6 and I have called `ProcessingProduct` object that is precisely what is linked to the parent listbox

```
public class ProcessingProduct
{
    public FullList Product { get; set; }
    public int Ready { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Cooks> NextAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Where `FullList`, `Cooks` and any other unnatural property are objects EF

This is my code of the View

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            int[] Cod_Prod = new int[] { 1298, 1299, 1300, 1301, 1302, 1302, 1303, 1304, 1305 };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetCooks();
    }

    RosendaEntities db = new RosendaEntities();

    public ObservableCollection<ProcessingProduct> DataSource { get; set; }

    public void UpdateDataSource()
    {
        lbCooks.ItemsSource = DataSource;
    }

    public void GetCooks()
    {
        var s = new ObservableCollection<ProcessingProduct>();
        foreach (int c in Cod_Prod)
        {
            s.Add(new ProcessingProduct
            {
                CookingProduct = db.FullList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == c),
                Ready = db.Art_Cook.Any(x => x.Cod_FullList == c && x.Cooks.Estate == (int)CooksState.Ready) ? (int)db.Art_Cook.Where(x => x.Cod_FullList == c && x.Cooks.Estate == (int)CookEstate.Ready).Sum(x => x.Quantity) : 0,
                Next = new ObservableCollection<Cooks>(db.Cooks.Where(x => x.Estate == (int)CookEstate.ProlongedCook || x.Estate == (int)CookEstate.Cooking).ToList())
            });
        }
        DataSource = s;
        UpdateDataSource();
    }
}
```

From the Cooks object from EF I create my ProcessingProduct collection that later assigned to ItemsSource, then I get this error, consider this:

- If you do not load or do not assign the `ProcessingProduct` property `Next` not throw that exception, so I assume that is the `NextAvailable` ListBox throwing this exception
- I'm not changing any element of the lists, or using the property `ItemsControl.Items`
- Before ObservableCollection type variables were IEnumerable, but reading several posts advised to use ObservableCollection, but changing it is not even my problem resolcion
  Any idea what it might be or where's the origin?
  any idea is welcome thanks in advance

**Edit**

I found that if I remove

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

from `NextAvailable` ListBox it loads properly, anyone knows why?
and how can I get them in horizontal Alignament whitout this exception?

Comment: Related; http://stackoverflow.com/q/9220702/546730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ItemsPanelTemplate` should be defined in `ItemsPanel` of `ListBox`. Update your declaration as

```
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

You can read about `ItemsPanel` and how it works [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx).